# Remove on behalf of in wordpress emails?

Tags: plugins

```
  //email to members
        $Memberdata_all ="select * from lwy_users where ID = $GuestID[$h]"; 
        $Memberdata_array = $wpdb->get_results($Memberdata_all, OBJECT);
        $to = $Memberdata_array[0]->user_email; 
        $from=$Sender_data_array[0]->user_email;     
        // Email subject and body text
        $link='abc';
        $subject = 'abc';
        $headers = "From: "membership@demo.com"\r\n";
        $message = "Hi $fromname, <br/> <br/>
        This is to inform you f.<br/> <br/>
        The following are the member details:<br/> <br/>


        MemberID:       $user_id   <br/>  
        MemberName:     $fromname $fromnamelastname  <br/>
         Club Name: $clubname<br/>    
         Club Location  $ClubCity<br/>
         Club Website:  $ClubWebsite<br/><br/><br/>  

        Here are the hosting details:<br/><br/>
        $noticetext <br/></br/>
        Please visit the link to accept the request  <a href='#'></a> <br/></br/><br/>
        If you have any questions, please contact the member directly at  $from <br/><br/>
        Regards<br/><br/>  

";  

add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
  $hostemail=wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

in Received email im getting...

```
golf@fs05.freshsites.co; on behalf of; WordPress <membership@demo.com>
```

please help me ,how can i remove  golf@fs05.freshsites.co; on behalf of; WordPress .i need only from membership@demo.com

Comment: This is a [theme my login plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-theme-my-login-on-behalf-of-wordpress) related issue which is off topic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This probably has something to do with the way your hosting company had configured their mail sending utilities that php is using. As an alternative you can try to use one of the plugins which enable you to send mail via SMTP